# Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1

Tags: image, html

```
pdf.drawImage(document.getElementById("Im0_2") ,0,0,1064,442);
```

it throws `Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1` in this line in my code n image is not getting loaded can any one help me out of this

Comment: What is pdf? Is that an object of some PDF generation engine for JS?

Comment: am converting pdf to html using jpedal and then converting html to epub using epublib, so jpedal provides me with a html code and thats wat pdf.drawImage is al about